# Как проигнорировать сериализацию Lazy полей в Spring Boot?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

Два класса связаны между собой:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meals")
public class Meal extends AbstractNamedEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    //getters, setters and other fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
    private Set<Meal> meals = Collections.emptySet();

    //getters, setters and other fields
}
```

Есть Spring Data Repository для работы с БД:

```
@Repository
public interface RestaurantRepository extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Integer> {

    @Query("select distinct r from Restaurant r join fetch r.meals m where m.date=?1")
    List<Restaurant> findByRestaurantMealDate(LocalDate date);
}
```

Достаю один ресторан - и начинается бесконечная сериализация по циклу - ресторан-блюда-ресторан...

Как запретить Spring сериализовать Lazy поля без явного обращения к геттерам через JOIN?

**@JsonIgnore использовать нельзя! Не подходит; т.к. в разных запросах нужны две стратегии - присоединять или не делать этого**

Answer (score 1):

1. Сделайте транспортный объект, который удобно передавать в JSON.
2. Сделать класс маппер который будет делать из  транспортного объекта сущность и обратно.

Таким образом вы сможете передавать в JSON такой объект который вам нужно, вне зависимости от вашей структуры данных. Даже при изменении внутренней структуры данных, вы сможете сохранить API.

Например так:

Сущность

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meals", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint( name="UK_MEALS_NAME", columnNames = {"MEAL_NAME"})
})
public class Meal {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqMealId")
@SequenceGenerator( name = "seqMealId", sequenceName = "SEQ_MEAL_ID",allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "MEAL_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "MEAL_NAME", nullable = false)
private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "RESTAURANT_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_MEAL_RESTAURANT"))
private Restaurant restaurant;

...  

}
```

Транспортный объект

```
public class MealDTO{

private Long id;
private String name;
private String restaurantName;

... 
}
```

Маппер

```
@Component
public class MealMapper{

public MealDTO toDTO(Meal meal){
    MealDTO dto = new MealDTO();
    dto.setId( meal.getId() );
    dto.setName( meal.getName() );
    dto.setRestaurantName(  meal.getRestaurant().getName() );
    return dto;
}

public List<MealDTO> toDTO (List<Meal> meals){
    List<MealDTO> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for( Meal meal : meals ){
        res.add(toDTO( meal ));
    }
    return res;
}

public Meal fromDTO(MealDTO dto){
    ...
}

public List<Meal> fromDTO(List<MealDTO> dto){
    ...
}

}
```

Comment: Я вводил кастомный обжект-маппер. Но я не знаю, как его зинжектить в спринг-бут. Пытался создать конфиг spring-mvc и там написать настройки; но у меня ничего не получилось - "не схватил"

Comment: Просто помечайте маппер аннотацией `@Component` и можете его внедрять в другие бины. Я добавил в ответ простенький пример. Только возник один вопрос - почему вы считаете что связь между сущностями ресторан и блюдо один ко многим? В теории одно блюдо готовят в разных ресторанах, и в одном ресторане готовят разные блюда - если исходить из этого то там должна быть связь многие ко многим. Возможно у вас другие требования.

Comment: да, у меня тестовое задание - создавать список ресторанов; к каждому из них добавлять свои блюда - и разрешить пользователю голосовать потом за эти рестораны.

а вы не могли бы дать пример подходящего мэппера, для внедрения?

Comment: Я написал пример маппера в ответе MealMapper